# Disordered json data in python

Tags: python, json

I have read the documentation in order to put my data into a json format to drop it after in a same format file.

This is an example,

```
import json

a='file.txt'
b='10:00:00'

metrics={
          'file:', a,
          'creation_time', b
        }

print(metrics)
```

Output:

```
{'10:00:00', 'file.txt', 'file:', 'creation_time'}
```

Why do data look disordered? How can I declare 'metrics', in order to obtain something like,

```
{'file:', 'file.txt', 'file:', '10:00:00'}
```

json.dumps(metrics) also did not work. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring your `metrics` variable as a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), not a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). You should change your `metrics` declaration as the following:

```
a = 'file.txt'
b = '10:00:00'

metrics = {
    'file': a,
    'creation_time': b
}

print(metrics)
```

Output:

```
{'file': 'file.txt', 'creation_time': '10:00:00'}
```

Adding a `json.dumps(metrics)` using this method you should get the following:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(metrics))
>>> {"file": "file.txt", "creation_time": "10:00:00"}
```